# Is it necessary to create a retina version of an app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina-display

Im creating an iOS game and I thought I was done until I test ran it on the iPad Retina simulator, and its extremely laggy. Is that a simulator glitch, or will it actually not work on the Retina iPad? I tried looking up if it was necessary and couldn't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the simulator for making any kind of judgment around performance. It's a simulator, not an actual device. It doesn't represent the actual conditions you'll be experiencing in hardware, and there are vast differences in terms of graphics and the rendering pipeline. If you're not testing your app on a hardware device you're doing a disservice to your potential users.

Do bear in mind the vast majority of devices being sold right now are retina. Many graphically rich games are able to support the hardware, so I suspect what you're seeing is either a) due to the simulator, or b) can be fixed with some optimisation.

Comment: Thanks @lxt, this is very helpful. By optimisation what exactly do you mean? Is there a type of thing you can write, like 'if retina display this' etc.

Comment: No, I mean run it on actual hardware, and if it's still sluggish then you can think about how to optimise your code and rendering to make it run faster. You absolutely, definitely should try running it on a retina iPad. The simulator is not representative of how your app will behave in real life...perhaps you could borrow one from a friend if you don't have one yourself?

Comment: Yeah I'll have to do that. This may be a very nooby question, but how do you get it on real hardware? Is that part of the developer package? As of right now I am only casually developing and just learning as I go so I haven't boughten the package yet. @lxt

Comment: Yes, you'll need to join the developer program. You can't actually submit apps until you're a member, so if you were looking to do that you would have had to have joined at some point anyway. I don't know what you're writing your game in (SpriteKit, Unity, Cocos2D, something else), but performance on the simulator on many of those frameworks often isn't that great compared to the actual hardware.

Comment: To be honest, although this game is cosmetic and fun, I think I've coded it badly, it doesn't use any of the game frameworks, (that I know of) it just uses a timer and CGRectIntersectsRect, perhaps apple would not even accept it. I'll see in time. This was all really good info. I'll check your answer as the most helpful. Thanks alot.

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh on yourself - keep at it, there are lots of games on the store that are coded just using `UIKit` and those various classes, and some of them are actually quite good!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is (kind of). The appstore has regulations on retina apps. I think that they only accept retina apps and a lot of people use retina devices so it might be a good idea to make it retina.

Comment: The images are retina though, is there any reason as to why the game itself is laggy, the images look fine on the larger screen?

Comment: Yeah true, I'm going to register now as a developer (haven't yet, was just seeing how I could develop), and try it on the hardware. Does apple explain how to transfer it to your device?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary. It may look pixelate on a retina device but it is not necessary. However, many people use retina devices (just consider this). Retina is just for looks most of the time. Good luck on your game!

Edit:

I looked into the developer and appstore requirements. Apple needs you to have a retina version or you might be looking at a turned down app. Anyways, have fun with this and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The part that is confusing me is the fact that its not the graphics that look pixelated, its the actual performance of the game, its laggy.

Comment: that is probably true! I find this interesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Designing for Retina display`

Building apps for Retina display involves creating two sets of images — one at 163ppi and another at 326ppi. After slugging our way through an app build or two, we feel confident that we have a decent workflow for attacking future Retina display app designs. Hopefully this information is of use to other designers

For More Information Please Check [HERE1](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/), [HERE2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/preparing-your-iphone-app-for-higher-resolutions--mobile-2254)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need your iOS game to run on all the devices glitch/lag free, when you go for publishing the application on the store it'll be turned down if it is not working on the retina version.

Possibly you are not using the images for retina display which are double the resolution

1. make sure resolution independence is turned on
2. design your artwork 2x as large as the actor (so a 100px actor should have artwork that is 200px)
3. ENSURE that all artwork is divisible by 4. (200/2 is 100, which is the size of the actor. 100/2 is 50 which is the pixel it will center on when placed in the game, you can't rest on .5 a pixel, it can turn out blurry)
4. Drag artwork into GS and program as normal.

I hope this solves your problem